# Wordpress Gutemberg RichText FormatType no wrap with tagName

Tags: javascript, wordpress, editor, richtext

I'm trying to add a custom button in my gutemberg toolbar on Wordpress to apply a class on selected element, but all I can do is to wrap selected text with a tag with my class.

Exemple:

```
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is if I select line 2 is that my class is applied to the li element, not wrapped with a span or something else with the class. Would be great that it applies also if I just set my cursor on the line without selecting all the line.

My code so far is this :

```js
const { registerFormatType } = wp.richText;
const { RichTextToolbarButton, RichTextShortcut } = wp.editor;

( function( wp ) {
    var CustomButton = ({ isActive, onChange, value }) => {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.blockEditor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                icon: 'image-flip-horizontal',
                title: 'Custom Button',
                onClick: () => {
                    onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(value, { type: 'robot/button' }));
                },
                isActive: isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'robot/button', {
            title: 'Custom button',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'myClass',
            edit: CustomButton,
        }
    );
} )( window.wp );
```

Is there an easy way to do it ? I can do it in tinyMCE with "wrapper => false" option.

Thank you